# Find where $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty a_n(z+3-i)^n$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

If the power series $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty a_n(z+3-i)^n$ converges at $5i$ and diverges at $-3i$ then the power series:

1. converges at $-2+3i$ and diverges at $2-3i$
2. converges at $2-3i$ and diverges at $-2+5i$
3. converges both at $2-3i$ and $-2+5i$
4. diverges both at $2-3i$ and $-2+5i$

Option a) is correct, but I don't know how to prove it, please help me.

Comment: what is $a_n$ ?

Comment: $a_n$ is not given in the question

Comment: so it's impossible to conclude... for exemple, if $a_n=0$ for all $n$, the series converge for any $z$.

Comment: Just wondering, why would option 2 be wrong? Is there missing something in the question?

Comment: GATE 2014 55th question

Comment: gate 2014 55th question

Comment: I would assume $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and not the index?

Comment: @Surb He assumes it diverges for $z=5i$ so it cannot be $a_n=0$ $\forall$ $n$.

Comment: From that stand point it makes sense than An cannot be zero, but for $5i$ and $-3i$ we get a complex number inside the brackets both having a magnitude of 5. That's why I would like to see some elaboration as of why answer a) is correct and not b) In answer b) $|2-3i|<5$ and $|-2+5i|>5$ I am sure I am missing something here, but I would like to know...

Answer (score 2):

A power series converges on a disk, in this case centered at $z=-3+i$.  At points on the boundary of the disk it may or may not converge.  So since we know it converges at $5i$ and diverges at $-3i$, both of which are $5$ units from $-3+i$, we know the disk has radius $5$.  Now look at (a).  One is closer than $5$ from $-3+i$ and the other is further away.  So it must converge at the first one and diverge at the second.